# Show user group membership in user info box

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

In today's discussion session at TUG2019, Jim Hefferon asked whether it would be possible to add a badge for user group membership to the user info box.

Here is a mockup of what I have in mind, where the TUG logo would be a direct link to the TUG homepage (similarly for other user groups, of course).

[image]

---

The incentive is that membership numbers are declining throughout TeX user groups across the world and seeing a lot of high-rep users on the site prominently showing off their user group memberships would hopefully get more new users interested in joining and thus funding the ongoing development of the TeX ecosystem.

Comment: @Henri Interesting suggestion! 1st thought: one could use the TUG badge as part of the own profile image, instead of a random gravatar image. 2nd thought: would you like to post a review of the discussion on http://tex-talk.net/ ? Promoting membership thoughts, also as reference.

Comment: I would use such a logo. But how to avoid (if you want avoid it) that it is used for arbitrary advertisement? And how to handle the case of multiple membership? I e.g. would then want TUG, Dante and Latex team.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This should of course not be user definable, but the user should be able to select from a list of user groups.  I think TUG maintains a [comprehensive list of user groups](https://tug.org/usergroups.html). (LaTeX team is not a really a user group, right?)

Comment: But then everybody sees that I'm a poor student not a member of any user group :(

Comment: @Skillmon Oh, come on, the student rates are not that expensive.  Write me an email and I shout you a one-year membership of the user group of your choice.

Comment: @HenriMenke you don't have to, and as soon as I have the money I'll join TUG and DANTE (I already checked multiple times how much the rates are), but currently I don't have the money. In a year I'm done with my studies, by that time I should be able to afford it.

Comment: @HenriMenke also my first comment wasn't meant seriously (though it is true).

Comment: I've asked for the StaffOverflow staff to comment here: I think we need some idea of whether this is even feasible at the 'back end'.

Comment: Isn't the problem though that for _users_ the 'user' group membership is at best a donation-to-development?

Comment: More answers on tex-se could be linked to articles in TUGBoat -- for those who'd like a fuller discussion of the topic -- and this would surely help TUG's membership as well.

Comment: Hiya! @JosephWright I happened across this post randomly rather than from your ping ... I'm going to guess that this would be pretty difficult for us to implement right now. The user cards are identical everywhere on the network and there's no way to add this without a major change to the usercards. I do think there's room for improvement but, for now, the best solution may be to use your profile text to state your membership/s (in text), which will be visible in your [expanded usercard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l28CP.png) (for higher-rep users).

Comment: @Catija I don't really believe that this is hard to implement. What about the winter bash hat mechanism? Isn't that essentially the same thing?

Comment: The hats are an overlay of the profile image that doesn't require a change to the usercard's format. You're suggesting a secondary image that has to have a site setting to activate it on the site and a place for users to upload the image and rearranging the content of the card to allow for it. What you've proposed works in your specific example but what about [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxJma.png)? We really don't want to wrap the timestamp.